# How to refresh a rootViewController after saving from a different ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a simple tableview based app, I have an addItem button that opens another viewController where I can add data and then save. The problem is the new record doesn't show up in the tableView after clicking save. I have tried using a delegate to refresh the table and couldn't get that working either. The only way I can see the new record that was added to the tableview is if I close the app and restart. See below.

```
- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {

mustRefresh = YES; // there is new record

ConditionsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ConditionsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//Create a Condition Object.
Condition *c = [[Condition alloc] init];

NSInteger newId = c.getNextConditionId;

Condition *cond = [[Condition alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:newId];

cond.condition_area = txtConditionArea.text;
cond.condition_detail = txtConditionDetail.text;
cond.condition_name = conditionName;

NSLog(@"    ///ABOUT TO SAVE THE CONDITION: %@ / %@ / %@", cond.condition_area, cond.condition_detail, cond.condition_name);

//Add the object
[appDelegate addCondition:cond];
[cond addCondition];

[appDelegate populateFromDatabase];

rvc.conditions = [appDelegate activeConditions];

// UPDATE THE TABLEVIEW
[rvc.tableView reloadData];

// release
[cond release];
[c release];

//Dismiss the controller.

[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{

    if (mustRefresh)
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(refreshTable)]) // this is just for check if 'refreshTable responds', prevents from crashing
            [self.delegate refreshTable];

}];

}
```

Comment: Use protocols and delegates..
Check this out, http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html.. maybe it'll help..

Comment: This reference is helpful. I am having a hard time specifically understanding how to get my expected result though. Any direction for my above example?

Comment: You need to have a BOOL variable that you'll be need to check if there's a newly added record.. then set it to yes for example then before you dismiss write something like 'if (boolVariable) [self.delegate refreshTable];'
or use, [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{ //call your delegate here  }];

should i post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using a protocol and what i have in mind on what you are trying to do..

```
// firstViewController.h 

#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface firstViewController : UIViewController <secondViewControllerDelegate>

@end

// firstViewController.m

@implementation firstViewController

// will be called by delegate
- (void)refreshTable
{
    // get fresh/updated data from your sqlite before refresh, to get the currently added data...

    self.dataSource = [yourFreshDataFromSqlite];

    [self.targetTable reloadData];
}
//..

- (void)someInstance
{
    secondViewController *svc = [[secondViewController alloc] init];

    svc.delegate = self; // this is very important

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}

@end

// secondViewController.h 

@protocol secondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)refreshTable;

@end 

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController 
{
    BOOL mustRefresh;
}

@property (weak) id <secondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

// secondViewController.m

- (void)someOtherInstance
{
    mustRefresh = YES; // there is new record
}

- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender 
{
    // ..
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{

        if (mustRefresh) // this also important, checks is you need to reload the table from the firstController
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(refreshTable)]) // this is just for check if 'refreshTable responds', prevents from crashing
                    [self.delegate refreshTable];

    }];
}
```

here is the log i got..

[image]

Hope i did missed something here.. hmmm.. Cheers..

Comment: I had to change the property (weak) to property (assign) to handle an error. But my original table still doesn't refresh. I like the delegate example you gave though, just didn't work for me yet. Any other ideas of why this would not work?

Comment: maybe you forgot about `mustRefresh = YES;` ? its working to me.. >.<

Comment: I did include this and also verified it is getting called. Maybe its an issue where the datasource itself isn't being updated, yet the sqlite db is?

Comment: Oh yes! that's your problem.. you are just reloading the table.. what you are missing is you need to repopulate your datasource from sqlite, before reloading the table.. table is reloaded but your data source is not updated.. YES?

Comment: No I am updated database and that is done here[cond addCondition];:

Comment: There is no problem loading the record into database because when I restart app, the new record is there.

Comment: yes, i know that it is saved.. the problem is the data source from your firstViewController.. see my edited answer under `-(void)refreshTable`..

try logging your dataSource inside `-(void)refreshTable`, and check if it is really updated...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79044/discussion-between-jroyce-and-0yeoj).